# Alternative to iTunes for managing videos?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, macos

I'm getting tired of fighting with Apple's iTunes to get it to play my non-iTunes media. [I've tried the 32-bit trick](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3206314?start=0&tstart=0), and MOV files I remove from the library and add back no longer show up in the `Movies` or `TV Shows` categories, so that trick fails, as well.

Every time there's an update, Apple breaks support for AVI, MP4 and — most recently — MOV files not purchased from Apple's iTunes store. So what alternatives to iTunes exist that manage to support a mix of media that Apple now seems to go out of its way to break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [Usher](http://manytricks.com/usher/), by ManyTricks, for $35. I haven't used it myself, but it looks great and follows iTunes/iPhoto's design principles. I trust ManyTricks to make a good app: they're behind my favorite window manager, Moom.

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to iTunes alternatives, I can think of three or four worthy alternatives.

**[Audirvana](http://code.google.com/p/audirvana/):**
A free, open-source tool which supports many formats and will allow you to upsampling for no cost at all.

**[Clementine](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/):**
Free source as well, a multi-platform player which is more of a music organizer and is pretty snappy.

**[Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/product/songbird-desktop.php):**
It's like the anti-iTunes and will provide everything you expect from a music player.

**[Ecote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ecoute/id402583177?mt=12)**:
It will cost you $8 in the MacApp Store, but it's worth it! It's very iOS-like and it integrates perfect with Mac OS X.

Although it will cost you some money, I strongly recommend Ecote!

Comment: I am not looking for music organizers, but iTunes-like applications which manage video media (as well as music).